# Finding the supply function from a production function

Tags: economics

Given the production function $f(z_1,z_2)=\sqrt{az_1+bz_2}$ where $z_1$ and $z_2$ are inputs, $a$ and $b$ are scalars; find the supply function: $y(p)$ output as a function of prices, and the profit function: $\pi(p)$ profit as a function of prices. I tried setting it up as a profit maximizing problem but everything cancels out and you can't find an optimal bundle of $z_1$ and $z_2$.

Comment: You need to explain what the various symbols represent.

Comment: @rogerl is that better?

Comment: Depends on how economists use the terms above. I am only speculating, but perhaps *supply* is defined as the rate of production? Also, the variables aren't defined at all. What are the $z$'s -- are they units, of what, the ingredients?